uncaughtExceptionHandler failed to catch exceptions in objective-c on Mac OS
Hi and I'm working on handling exceptions in an app.
My exception handler code is as below.
In AppDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
static void uncaughtExceptionhandler(NSException* exception);

In AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppDelegate
static void uncaughtExceptionhandler(NSException* exception) {
  //log related information
}

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionhandler);
}

In order to test this handler, I raised an expection in my code.
In MyWindowController.m
- (void)testHandler {
  @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"TestException" reason:@"TestOnly" userInfo:nil];
}

But noting was logged and it seemed uncaughtExceptionhandler function was not triggered.
I'm not sure if my exception handler code is right.

Debug it and add a breakpoint in uncaughtExceptionhandler to see if it's being called.

Hi @trojanfoe, I have debugged it with break point in XCODE. testHandler was called but uncaughtExceptionhandler wasn't.

AppKit catches exceptions. From where or when do you call testHandler? Have you tried an exception breakpoint?

@Willeke I have checked the timing and place for testHandler and found something. If I call testHandler just after NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler, uncaughtExceptionhandler can catch this exception. But if I call testHandler in other function like applicationWillTerminate, uncaughtExceptionhandler failed to catch the exception.

-[NSApplication terminate:] catches this exception.

May be some 3rd party lib also calling NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler to.
